# Go profiler (pprof) timing discrepancy

Tags: go, runtime, profiling, gperftools

When I measure the run time of my Go program with Linux's `time` utility, I get the following output:

```
real    1m9.177s
user    7m1.788s
sys     0m39.016s
```

When I look at the output of the same exact program execution in Go's pprof CPU profiler, I get the following output:

```
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands)
(pprof) top
143.32s of 176s total (81.43%)
```

Where is the pprof getting this 176s figure from? It is neither the clock time nor the CPU time. I am running this program with `GOMAXPROCS` set to 8, and I have a feeling this has something to do with it. How exactly does pprof measure run time, and why is it different from linux's `time`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `time` utility and the `pprof` tool operate in different ways and should be used in different ways. Don't try to reconcile them. `time` measures near exact times for the program; `pprof` measures relative times for functions and methods. `pprof` is an intrusive statistical sample. When CPU profiling is enabled, the Go program stops about 100 times per second and records a sample consisting of the program counters on the currently executing goroutine's stack. Sampling has a cost and the results are estimates of the actual population.

Use `time` to measure the overall actual CPU time for the program, that is absolute time. Use `pprof` to estimate where most of the time was spent in the functions and methods using relative time percentages.  `pprof` identifies the bottlenecks. For actual CPU times, use Go `testing` package benchmarks.

For an example, see [Profiling Go Programs](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs):

> By using Go's profiling tools to identify and correct specific
>   bottlenecks, we can make the Go loop finding program run an order of
>   magnitude faster and use 6x less memory.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like some bug. Possibly some known bug. What pprof does in order to output 176s is multiplying known sampling period by number of samples. And it should be reasonably accurate w.r.t. total cpu time spent by the process (system + user).

Is there any chance that your program spawns some work via subprocesses? That could be one way to explain difference.